# ImageResizer not working on jpg files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

Trying to troubleshoot an issue with ImageResizer not working on JPG files. PNG files are working fine. Implementation is using ImageResizer 3.4.3.103 on a ASP.Net MVC site. Working/Non-Working examples, diagnostics output, and related ImageResizer Web.Config entries are included below.

**Working Example:**

- https://www.roanoke.edu/ui/images/logo.png?width=10

**Broken Examples:**

- https://www.roanoke.edu/assets/Images/admissions/FinancialAidInfographic.jpg?width=10
- https://www.roanoke.edu/assets/Images/Navigation/Admissions%20Updates/img_admissions-updates.jpg?width=2

**ImageResizer Diagnostics Output**
https://gist.github.com/OtoNoOto/2fb5c48937240f970ac395bf7b965ea0

**ImageResizer Web.Config Entries**
https://gist.github.com/OtoNoOto/fe3e02bf12982047995a3af8e76277e7

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Examples seem to be working from here. What HTTP headers and response are you getting?

Comment: @NathanaelJones You are seeing the broken image examples resized to 10px? THe images themselves load fine. The issue is the resizing is not working (ref: the URL query string ?width=10 in the URL).

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version? There have been hundreds of bug fixes and there is better MVC compat.

Comment: @NathanaelJones I updated the dll to 4.2.5 and still not working (can reproduce issue using original links provided). Here is a link to the new Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.2.5 (https://gist.github.com/OtoNoOto/c5c488563563e23dc5429cf7e04c9a94).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like other software installed is stealing .jpg requests so that they don't reach ImageResizer.

You might try disabling other HTTP modules one at a time until .jpg URLs work, or using the debugger and tracing the request in Visual Studio to find what code it is hitting.